# Ubuntu-Windows 7 dual boot, windows broken

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, 64-bit

And I'm considering reinstalling windows 7, should I remove ubuntu beforehand?

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/black-screen-before-login-after-installing/ca7e7876-1b1d-4cd1-aceb-d69a8eafdd10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time i was in the same situation , So if you delete windows partition it will affect grub for sure, actually in my case that happened . Then you have recover it as mentioned by guru prasad.

So re-installing both is better , before deleting both the OS do-

1. Backup home
2. open /var/cache/apt/archive and copy all the .deb files somewhere else after re-installing Ubuntu , copy them to the same folder and install your software’s by normal `apt-get install` it will use those .deb files and little from internet to install.

Answer (score 0):

- you dont need to remove ubuntu.You can just delete the windows partition on ubuntu and reinstall windows on the same partition.
- To delete a windows partition,you need to install *gparted partition editor* on ubuntu.Run the below commands on terminal to install gparted,

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gparted
  ```
- Open gparted ,locate the windows7 partition and format it to ntfs filesystem.
- Then bootup the windows-live-disk.During windows installation select the custom option and then select the ntfs partition you formatted it on gparted and install windows to it.

Comment: Actually I have a partition will restore my computer to factory settings. No windows disk.